# Jersey PathParam with HTTP 405 error

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I'm using jersey for my rest server, and **I got a HTTP 405 error, when I try to forward POST request to relative GET resource.**

```
@Path("/")
public class MyResource {

    @POST
    @Path("/{method}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String postRequest(@PathParam("method") String method, @Context UriInfo uriInfo, String body) throws IOException {
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonObject root = parser.parse(body).getAsJsonObject();
        JsonObject params = root;

        if (root.has("method")) {
            method = root.get("method").getAsString();
            params = root.getAsJsonObject("params");
        }

        UriBuilder forwardUri = uriInfo.getBaseUriBuilder().path(method);
        for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> kv : params.entrySet()) {
            forwardUri.queryParam(kv.getKey(), kv.getValue().getAsString());
        }

        return new SimpleHttpClient().get(forwardUri.toString());

    }

    @GET
    @Path("/mytest")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getTest(@QueryParam("name") String name)   {
        return name;
    }

}
```

curl -X POST -d {"method":"mytest","params":{"name":"jack"}}  localhost/anythingbutmytest

curl -X GET localhost/mytest?name=jack

**These two curl above work fine. But I get a 405 error , when I try to request like this:**

curl -X POST -d {"method":"mytest","params":{"name":"jack"}}  localhost/mytest

```
javax.ws.rs.NotAllowedException: HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.MethodSelectingRouter.getMethodRouter(MethodSelectingRouter.java:466)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.MethodSelectingRouter.access$000(MethodSelectingRouter.java:94)   
......
```

What should I do?

-------------------------------------Update-------------------------------------

curl -X POST -d {"method":"mytest","params":{"name":"jack"}}  localhost/mytest

This curl work fine, when I add a post method like below. **But I will write a same POST method for every GET Method like that, is there any other solution?**

`@POST
    @Path("/mytest")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String postMyTest(@Context UriInfo uriInfo, String body) throws Exception {
        return postRequest(uriInfo.getPath(), uriInfo, body);
    }`

Besides, is there any other way to re-route POST request to a method in the same class without building a new HTTP request?

Comment: I think this is by design (specification). You may need to just create an extra `@POST @Path("/mytest")` method to handle POSTs just for that specific route.

Comment: Thanks, It work fine when I add a `@POST @Path("/mytest")` method.  But it seems like a little redundant  , see my update.

Answer (score 0):

You should make

```
    @POST
    @Path("/mytest")
```

and not "getTest" method.Reason is below.

Command

```
curl -X POST -d {"method":"mytest","params":{"name":"jack"}} localhost/anythingbutmytest
```

will accept because of

```
@Path("/{method}") .
```

But

```
curl -X POST -d {"method":"mytest","params":{"name":"jack"}} localhost/mytest
```

will not accept because of

```
@GET
@Path("/mytest")
```

POST does not match GET.

Comment: Yes, it work fine when I add a  `@POST @Path("/mytest")` method. But Why `@POST @Path("/{method}")` can not accept `POST /mytest` ?  Is it a jersey bug ?