# Method not allowed when using regex in @Path with jersey

Tags: java, spring-boot, jersey-2.0

I am trying to provide endpoints that will listen on multiple versions, i.e `/v1/test` and `/v2/test`. In order not to duplicate my code, I use jersey's ability to use patterns in the `@Path` annotation.
Let's assume I want to provide a GET and a POST endpoint:

```
@Controller
@Slf4j
@Path("/")
public class TestController {
    @GET
    @Path("/v{version:[12]}/test")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String test1(@PathParam("version") String version) {
        System.out.println(String.format("GET /v%s/test called", version));
        return "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}";
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/v{version:[12]}/test")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String test2(@PathParam("version") String version) {
        System.out.println(String.format("POST /v%s/test called", version));
        return "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}";
    }
}
```

That works fine.

If I, however, try to use a specific path for the GET endpoints and use a pattern for the POST endpoint, I run into trouble.
Here the controller that would not work:

```
@Controller
@Slf4j
@Path("/")
public class TestController {

    @GET
    @Path("/v1/test")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String test1() {
        System.out.println("GET /v1/test called");
        return "{\"foo\":\"bar1\"}";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/v2/test")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String test2() {
        System.out.println("GET /v2/test called");
        return "{\"foo\":\"bar2\"}";
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/v{version:[12]}/test")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String test3(@PathParam("version") String version) {
        System.out.println(String.format("POST /v%s/test called", version));
        return "{\"foo\":\"barPOST\"}";
    }

}
```

Doing `GET /v1/test` or `GET /v2/test` works fine, `POST /v1/test` however does not.

I get a `405 Method Not Allowed` Exception.
As far as I got it the exception is thrown in the `MethodSelectingRouter` when it recognizes the path, but cannot find a method with the appropriate HTTP verb.
The issue seems to be that it picks the most specific path (`/v1/test` in my case) for which it does not know the `POST` verb.

Does anybody have an idea how to avoid this problem?
Cheers

**PS**: I am using spring boot with jersey (i.e. `spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-boot-starter-jersey`) in version `1.5.2.RELEASE`

Comment: It's a bug either in the specification or the implementation. Not sure which one. It seem this case was not considered. The regex path doesn't get added to the candidate methods as there is already an exact match (path) found (even though the HTTP method doesn't match). Only thing you can do is just add POST method(s) that don't use regex. Similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44538487/2587435). I said the same thing.

Comment: thank you! mhh that's a shame!